# Get the value of a variable using the text *name* of the variable in VBA

Tags: vba

I'm trying to loop through a list of variables named a1, a2, etc... and construct the name of the variable on the fly, something like this:

```
a1 = 7
For RowNum = 1 to 10
    MyVar = "a" & RowNum
    'use MyVar in calculation
    MsgBox MyVar
Next RowNum
```

The problem is I need the *value* of MyVar, and all I get is the name.  Here, in the first iteration of the loop, MsgBox shows "a1" and I need 7.  I've tried many permutations using .Value and I just get compile or runtime errors.

How do I get the value of a variable from its name in text?  Can this be done in VBA?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is what arrays are for.  Or a scripting dictionary.  There's no mechanism in the VBA language for "evaluation" of code, as you might find in (eg) javascript.

Comment: You're thinking in PHP or something. For this to work you would need *reflection*, which isn't a language feature of VBA. Use arrays.

Comment: Are you actually wanting the value of a **variable** called `a1`, or are you just after the value of the **Excel cell** `A1` (i.e. you want `Range("a" & RowNum).Value`)?

Comment: 1& 2.  I've tried an array of the variable names dimensioned as string.  Same problem - ArrayName(1) gives me "a1", not the value of the variable a1.  3.  I want Range("A" & a1).Value or Range("A" & ArrayName(RowNum)).Value.  Neither of those works.

Comment: I went a different way and got it to work.  I used an array of integers and set the elements of the array to the values of the a(n) variables whenever they changed.  Then Range("A" & ArrayName(RowNum)).Value gets the correct answer.  Thanks all of you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a Dictionary:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim myVars As Object
    Dim myVar As Variant
    Dim RowNum As Long

    Set myVars = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    myVars("a1") = 7
    myVars("a5") = "xyz"
    myVars("hello") = 42

    For RowNum = 1 To 10
        myVar = myVars("a" & RowNum)
        'use MyVar in calculation
        MsgBox "a" & RowNum & " contains " & myVar
        If RowNum = 1 Then
            MsgBox Range("D" & myVars("a" & RowNum)).Address
        End If
    Next RowNum

End Sub
```